# Reverse osmosis filter constantly draining

Tags: plumbing, water

I have a reverse osmosis system (Watts fmr04-man) that started constantly draining. It's been installed for 5 years. 2 years ago, it did this and I replaced the filters and membrane, which resolved the issue. However, that gets expensive and I'd like to do more troubleshooting.

When I shut off the pressure tank valve, the draining stops within 5 seconds. I believe this means the ASO is working and so is the check valve. When I turn it back on, the draining resumes within a couple of minutes.

What are my next steps?

Comment: what is the tank pressure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, was the membrane. Replaced it, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If your water supply to the RO unit is via a saddle valve, replace the saddle valve with something that provides a higher flow rate